# "Standard" method for refreshing production cubes SSAS

Tags: sql, ssas

Relatively new to SSAS.

Just wondering what is best practice for refreshing data in the production environment.

One "method" under discussion is refreshing the data in Dev, checking it's fine and does not kill the cube. Then copying the cube from Dev to Live (changing connection strings etc)

The other is simply refreshing the cube data via an SSIS package.

Is there a preferred method that most people use or is it down to personal choice?

Comment: Another possibility would be the "Synchronize" feature described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174928.aspx. It is not described there in detail, but you can also synchronize using XMLA, which lets you include a synchronize int a SQL Server Agent job. There are some downsides of synchronizing, however, the most important is this: As the name of the database must match, synchronizing only works between different servers, you cannon synchronize database QA to database Prod on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use an SSIS package, mainly for the logging.  I send the logs to the msdb..sysssislog table so you get detailed logging with minimal effort.  It's very useful when a build fails, as SSAS typically puts out hundreds of irrelevant "process cancelled" messages.

I do all the design work in Visual Studio, with an Environment configuration pointing to the DEV environment, then switch to a PROD configuration to release it.  Note the VS environment setting for SSAS allows varying connection strings, so there is no post-release process to worry about.